# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: typescript, angular

I am getting this build error when I use a parameter decorator in a method. The class implements an interface. Here are the interface and class:

```
export interface IClient{
    getServerConfig(): Observable<Response> ;

    getDashboard(): Observable<Response>;

    deploy(channelId: string): Observable<Response>;
}

export class Client implements IClient {

    public constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http, @Inject(Model) private config: Model) {
        super(http, config);
    }

    public getServerConfig(): Observable<Response> {
        return null;
    }

    public getDashboard(): Observable<Response> {
        return null;
    }

    public deploy(@Body('param') channelId: string): Observable<Response> {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When building I get this error

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

right at the deploy function.

The problem seems to be the parameter decorator next to the channelId parameter. Now I can't just remove it as I need it so I am wondering if there is a way to keep the interface definition and the decorator. Decorators are not allowed in interfaces so that is not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Quickest fix is to do `const BodyAny:any = Body` and use `BodyAny`. Otherwise fix the type definition for `Body`.

Comment: Thanks, you just pointed me in the right direction. I overlooked a parameter of the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and the problem was a missing `@Injectable()` on the service it was complaining about.

Simply importing and adding the decorator sorted it out!